# Overwrite entire state in redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

This is yet another novice question about `redux`. In my app, i would like to be able to load the state from a text file, i.e. to be able to completely re-initialise the *whole* state object. So I don't want to *reset* the `state` to an initial value, but *replace* it with a new one. (FYI the application stores data merely in the browser's *localStorage*. Also, so far I have followed the awesome tutorial from http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/index.html) I have tried several approaches, but none of them have yielded results. For example, in my `reducers/index.js` i have:

```
export default function App (state = {}, action) {
  return {
    todos: todos(state.todos, action),
    ...
    global: global(state, action)
  }
}
```

In `reducers/global.js` I have:

```
const global = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_DB_FROM_FILE':
      return action.fileContents;
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What happens is that the `state` object, oddly (or not :)) enough, gets a new field called `global` which contains the original state (and not the one read from the file) and it even gets nested for a couple of levels (so i have a replica of the `state` at `state.global.global.`)

I am aware of the hackiness of this approach, even willing to accept a fundamental flaw (due to my ignorance) in my setup, still i haven't been able to find a simple and unambiguous answer to my problem.

As always, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know little about redux, but based on what I know about JavaScript I would say you need something like this:

```
// reducers/index.js

export default function App (state = {}, action) {
  state = global(state, action);
  return {
    todos: todos(state.todos, action),
    ...
  };
}
```

So the reducer named `global` has a chance to replace the whole state object at once.